# How to compile a section in Prefix.pch of a Xcode project once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, precompile

The `Prefix.pch` as below.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define BUNDLE_NAME XXXBundle
#define LOADER_CLASS XXXBundleLoader

extern NSBundle *BUNDLE_NAME;
#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [BUNDLE_NAME localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]

#ifdef RUN_ONCE

NSBundle *BUNDLE_NAME;

@interface LOADER_CLASS : NSObject @end

@implementation LOADER_CLASS

+ (void)load
{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    BUNDLE_NAME = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CXAFMResources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
  });
}

@end

#endif

#endif
```

`.pch` will be added to the header of every `.m` file, so Class define here will compile multiple times without defining `RUN_ONCE`, but what I need is let this `RUN_ONCE` section compile only one time. I add a compiler flag `-DRUN_ONCE` to a `.m` file of my project to solve this. I wonder if there is a one-step solution for the `#ifdef RUN_ONCE` that don't need to add flag?

No, I don't want another `.m` file. I want to keep this snippet works by only copying to another `.pch`.

Comment: you should move implementation to .m file

Comment: Thanks but I don't want another .m or add it to another .m file.

Comment: why? put implementation in header is always bad. even worser to put in .pch

Comment: Why on earth do you want a class implementation in the PCH? That's not what the PCH is for.

Comment: Yes I know it's bad but not always. Once this work, I could localize iOS static lib in minimal way — not need to add a implementation file, not need to add a flag for a file. And it's very portable by only copying to another iOS static lib.